# Recommendations sought for Image Processing books

Tags: ios, image-processing, ocr, smartphone, image-recognition

*[I am unsure how to solicit book recommendations here on StackOverflow.  I'd appreciate any pointers.]*

I am embarking on creating an Augmented Reality smartphone (iOS) app that needs to recognize shapes and shades in images taken with the smartphone.  Being able to scan barcodes and QR codes is important.  Being able to do OCR would be great.

Before I go looking for samples, PD and open source projects, I thought I should brush up on the state of Image Processing and read some books.  While I don't mind reinventing, I definitely don't want to be rediscovering the wheel.

Are there books you've read and recommend?

Comment: I think stackexchange is the place. Not sure myself though. I have seen many of these book requests being moved or closed down.

Answer (score 0):

Augmented reality apps are great and the people who work on them, are awesome. I wish you good luck. To begin with, you need to get hold of a few things. I am not much of an iOS developer here, but I worked on a similar application last year.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4qfFrZGKlA

1. A good location based places service.
2. A real-time image processing.

For location based data, I used the Foursquare API. Of course there are better options, but their API is easier to use.

Real time image processing- I have not much of an idea, but I have heard a lot about this book at college, from people who worked on DIP projects o processing gigantic map tiles.

> Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods and Steven L. Eddins (2004).
>   Digital Image Processing using MATLAB

But since that one will have annoying references to some great Matlab functions that you cannot use in your development environment with ease, this book is a good alternative.

> Wilhelm Burger and Mark J. Burge (2007): Digital Image Processing: An
>   Algorithmic Approach Using Java.